# Can someone explain this interference phenomena? (video)

Tags: circuit-design, interference

It seems like maybe static? or EMI? I realized the proximity of my hand was causing this issue. (see video below)

its clearly not the photo sensor as you can see in the video, and approaching the circuit from any side causes the issue. actually wiring up my nodemcu to the board does not cause these results, but neither does using the same wemos in a protoboard with the same circuit. I'm stumped

(in the schematic I used CC RGB LEDS but finally settled on CA LEDS in the final design.)

any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Video](https://youtu.be/ZqMlXyEBFpU)

[image: layout and schematic]

Comment: You could still mention THE issue in the post.

Comment: sorry but i'm not sure what the issue is exactly. anyways I added the word interference if that makes you feel better :)

Comment: The only thing steady in the video was the intro titles. It looks like a very jerky camera on zoom with a poor or malfunctioning steadycam feature.

Comment: Maybe if you bother to explain what your circuit does and how it is implemented, maybe someone can explain.

Comment: Also, what the heck the "nodemcu" and "wemos" supposed to mean? Could you formulate your issue in engineering terms? Not everyone is deeply familiar with toy electronics market and youth jargon.

Comment: What do you mean "you don't know what the issue is"? The issue is that the LEDs flash when your finger is near the unit, apparently.

Comment: @AliChen nodemcu and wemos appear to be software packages for ESP8266 chips

Comment: @Ali Chen should I also explain to you what an arduino is? one google search of either of those boards will give you a wealth of information.

Comment: Dear Alex, if you are not willing to explain what kind of wires you managed to craft around which pin of your particular toy, I will not be able to explain to you how electromagnetic field around your palm induces parasitic voltages into high-impedance inputs. And, BTW, google has a wealth of information about electromagnetic fields too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your microcontroller might have inputs configured as open drain without pull-up or pull-down resistors. That way every parasitic capacitance such as capacitance between wire and your finger might change the value read and therefore turn LEDs on. Of course, without proper schematic it's just my best blind guess.

Comment: that sounds reasonable but just to clarify I'm not actually touching anything.

Comment: Your body still acts like a capacitor ... how much depends on what your wearing, the humidity, how near to other circuit (usually mains) and how near your finger is... The MCU datasheet has advise for minimum pull down/up resistors or register configuration to stop this by using internal pull down/up resistors.

Comment: @Alex, to test the body capacitance idea, try touching ground somewhere as you wave your hands around.  That should change things... you still may see something, but it should be different depending on whether you are touching ground or not.

Comment: +1. The common case is that the gadget is likely powered from a wall AC-DC adapter, which is floating. Leakage inside the power adapter usually leads to about 50-60V AC voltage relative to Earth ground, where OP effectively stands. Typical leakage source has about 100k of impedance. So you have 50V at 60Hz into body over the coupling capacitor (between body and wires).